# C# Browser version get wrong version for windows 11

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer-11

C# Browser version get wrong version for windows 11(last windows update v:11.187.14393.0)

```
HttpBrowserCapabilities browser = Request.Browser;
Console.WriteLine("Result:" + browser.MajorVersion.ToString());
```

Result:7

Comment: And what user-agent string is your browser sending?

Comment: navigator.userAgent : "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.3)"

Answer (score 0):

Go into Internet Explorer and hit F12.  Check the emulation tab.

Document Mode and User Agent string are what determine the browser version.

change both those settings to

Document Mode: Edge (default)
User Agent String: Default

Comment: document.documentMode : 7    --- 
navigator.userAgent : "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.3)"